# Laravel htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I've setup a new install of Laravel on my local. It appears there are issues with htaccess or Apache settings. I've researched for a number of hours and tried everything I read.

- OSX Lion 10.7.5
- MAMP 3.0.5
- PHP 5.5.10
- mod_rewrite is being loaded.

My development server works with other sites. This is the first time I am trying Laravel 4.

I get a 403 Forbidden on the welcome page which is located at website.dev:8888/

Apache gives me this error: Directory index forbidden by Options directive

Here is my .htaccess file content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here are a few additional actions I've taken:

- AllowOverride is set to All in httpd.conf
- Added virtual host code section to httpd-vhosts.conf
- verified that the hosts file contains a line for the site 127.0.0.1 website.dev

I've also tried various lines in the htaccess which I found in articles and I also restarted apache each time I made changes to the conf files. No routes work. When I go to website.dev:8888/public I get a blank page, no error. If I go to a route I created such as website.dev:8888/users I get a 404 not found error.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just making sure, "public" folder is your web root? (it should!)

Comment: No I don't think it is. How do I set it so it is?

Comment: easiest would be to change `DocumentRoot "/srv/httpd"` in httpd.conf to ie. `DocumentRoot "/srv/httpd/public"`

Answer (score 39):

This solution worked fine, best solution ever for me. Paste this code into root htaccess. That's all. Leave all other files as they are

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Where did this code originate? (How does this actually solve the OPs specific problems?)

Comment: Use this for root folder

Comment: Explanation for this solution would be appreciated, specifically parts which point redirection either to public or server -script, but it does seem to work.

Comment: First goes to public/* and then points to server.php. So no need to include /public/ anywhere else ;)

Comment: Anyway, thank you, it worked for me perfectly. Hope one day to understand the code, but for today, copy paste is ok

Comment: @MohammadH. I do not have the problem of "/public" in the url. My only problem is that I have an unstyled app. My css js files are not loading. I am on laravel 6. I have tried all the solutions in this post.

Comment: this works for absolutes or relatives path, but will sometimes cause troubles when you have to deal with symbolik links

Answer (score 24):

In the root path create a .htaccess file with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

In public directory create a .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

if you have done any changes in public/index.php file correct them with the right path then your site will be live.

what will solve with this?

- Hosting issue of laravel project.
- Css not work on laravel.
- Laravel site not work.
- laravel site load with domain/public/index.php
- laravel project does not redirect correctly

Answer (score 7):

### Answer

Heres what I found that worked. Delete the `.htaccess` file inside the `/public` directory and then put the following into the laravel installation's document root.

---

### Clarification

So for clarification if your laravel application is installed at `/public_html/laravel` you will look inside `/public_html/laravel/public` and delete the `.htaccess` file there. Then inside the `/public_html/laravel` directory make a new file called `.htaccess`

---

## Copy the code below to a new .htaccess file in the doc root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

## Please note

As [Concordus Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284185/concordus-applications) noted in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267967/htaccess-for-clean-urls-not-being-read-by-apache/#answer-11268084) make sure that the `Loadmodule mod_rewrite` is uncommented (make sure there is not a `#` symbol behind it in your apache config file)

Concordus Applications also noted that you should have `AllowOverride` set to the appropriate setting. The example they gave was the following.

```
<Directory "/some/absolute/path/htdocs">
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Please make sure to restart your apache server if you made any changes to your apache config file.

Answer (score 5):

The framework ships with a `public/.htaccess` file that is used to allow URLs without `index.php`. If you use Apache to serve your Laravel application, be sure to enable the `mod_rewrite` module.

If the `.htaccess` file that ships with Laravel does not work with your Apache installation, try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer worked but not with laravel passport authentication.

There is a need to add some header tweaking:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Answer (score 5):

This .htaccess will remove /public/ from your URL and force https://

Put this .htaccess in your root folder without renaming server.php file to index.php
this .htaccess will do everything

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 

</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you get server errors, you might need to add the following to the .htaccess file right after "RewriteEngine On":
"RewriteBase /"
Works for me now on Ionos/1&1 webhosting.

Comment: @ftw I do not have the problem of "/public" in the url. My only problem is that I have an unstyled app. My css js files are not loading. I am on laravel 6. I have tried all the solutions in this post.

Comment: @umair Few things to check.
1. Check your APP_URL
2. Make sure you are using {{ asset('/css/app.css') }} some thing like this
3. Check your network tab to read what status codes you are getting.

Comment: @ftw Before I go with your solution, I did ctrl + u and this is what I saw. The /public is repeated twice in the url. See image https://i.postimg.cc/R00GQkXQ/Untitled.jpg

Comment: @ftw Here is the github repo https://github.com/cmate5614530/inventory-management

Comment: @ftw Where to put {{ asset('/css/app.css') }} by the way?

Comment: @ftw APP_URL is correct. In the network tab the statuses are 404. As for the /public appearing twice was because I was using ASSET_URL=public in .env file. What now?

Comment: @umair is this your actual repo? github.com/cmate5614530/inventory-management

Comment: @ftw No this is not my repo. I found where to make changes. resources\views\layout\main.blade.php I tried {{ asset('/css/app.css') }} but it is not working either. WHat else?

Comment: @PushkrajJori No this is not my repo. I found where to make changes. resources\views\layout\main.blade.php I tried {{ asset('/css/app.css') }} but it is not working either. WHat else?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's very hard to guess the issue. Create new public repo and upload your config folder, resources folder and public folder. and share the repo url here to get appraised.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have .htaccess files in both /wwwroot and /public. The content is different though:
**wwwroot/.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**wwwroot/public/.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This works for me in ionos hosting

Comment: This works only with the default URL (localhost:8000) but not when calling other routes like this localhost:8000/Mycontroller.  We need to include the public again to make these things work.

Answer (score 1):

Create new .htaccess file in root folder.
and put this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

and add this code in .htaccess at end in public/.htaccess file

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+/)?public/(\S*) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
   RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution Copy and Paste The Code Below Into Your `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase/
RewriteRule ^-$public/index.php[L]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

The  block checks if the mod_rewrite module is available in Apache.
RewriteEngine On enables the URL rewriting engine.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] redirects all incoming requests to the 'public' directory.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

This configuration is often used in web applications to route requests through a specific directory (in this case, 'public'). The comments provide a quick overview of each line's purpose for better understanding and documentation.

Comment: This looks similar to several other existing answers, but with less detail. How does this improve upon what's already here? Why should we use this instead of the others?