# "Internal Server Error" when deploying Laravel app on VPS

Tags: php, laravel, apache, deployment, vps

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel 5.6 app on a Debian 9 based VPS with Apache, but the server seem to be unable to handle the requests when i try to access the first page,and i keep having

> "Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request."

I've already looked at this

[Laravel htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620505/laravel-htaccess)
[Getting a 500 Internal Server Error on Laravel 5+ Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543175/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-on-laravel-5-ubuntu-14-04)
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

My .htaccess file that i placed inside the public folder

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The configuration file places inside /etc/apache/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName picodem.dev

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/picodem-project/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/picodem-project>
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't have a domain name yet, and the `picodem.dev` is just dummy, so i'm  accessing the app via the Browser using the IP address of the VPS, but i'm still not sure what's causing the problem...

Comment: Is your live domain called `picodem.dev`? because your vhost has `ServerName picodem.dev`

Comment: That's a dummy domain (fake) because i don't have one yet, so i'm trying to access the App using the server IP. could that be the cause of the issue ?

Comment: Yes that can be the issue. Also any error occurred on server level, you would be able to see it in /var/log/apache/error.log. Check this file and the error details should be there

Comment: Have you tried placing that .htaccess file in the *root* of your project? I just went through this headache launching a Laravel 5.7 app on Azure linux. I also had to add URL::forceScheme('https'); to the bottom of my routes/web.php file

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>          <-- I used this